# Do I really need to save instance state

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that doesn't support screen rotation. Do I really need to save the instance state of all my activities? How rare is it for android to kill activities? If the activity is killed and restored it will just look to the user as it did when they first came to it, which was probably quite a while ago anyway if the system has killed it. It doesn't seem like such a bad user experience to me if it is rarely going to happen. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on the content of your view and on how important it is for the current state to be saved.

Comment: For rotation, just add that you handle orientation changes to your manifest-  instead of killing your activity it will just call onConfigurationChanged.  In the end a large percentage of apps do this.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, and sadly a lot of those same apps break if I get a call and go back to them, or I change timezone, or I go to settings and back etc etc.  It's not good practice to pretend that the life cycle is not there and, after all, it's easy to deal with.  I'd go further and suggest that a lot of those app developers consider testing something that users should do and might perhaps test themselves with the odd screen rotation - "Yeh, it works.  Get it on the market".

Comment: @Simon All of those things aren't app restarts.  They call onPause/onResume which you definitely have to handle.  But they don't create a new activity.  So on this I'm going to disagree-  the idea of destroying and recreating the activity on rotation was braindead by google, and the correct way of dealing with their idiocy is to use the loophole they left to remove it.  Heck, even most of Google's apps do that.

Comment: Totally disagree.  Any of those things can result in a restart, and often do, since Android can kill that activity as soon as it leaves the foreground.  There is no contract that it will not restart for any reason.  And far from brain dead, the life cycle is there exactly to deal with this.  Trying to separate rotation from any other out of app event that may kill the activity is the real problem here.

Comment: @GabeSechan  Your description of android:configChanges as a "loophole" is positively dangerous and results in many bugs.  When you use this, you are saying "OK Android.  I know what I'm doing and I will handle the side effects myself".  What actually happens is that developers read it as "I can't be bothered with all that life cycle stuff.  I'll workaround it".  Try this, write a simple app with a big juciy bitmap background and logcat in onCreate().  Fill your phones memory as full as you can. Then try some of the above scenarios a few times and examine the logcat output.  Notice anything?

Comment: @Simon  Yes, background processes get killed.  You have to be prepared for that.  It has nothing to do with configuration changes via rotation, which is an idiotic mistake by google that causes more problems than it ever fixed.  You're talking about a completely separate issue.

Comment: @GabeSechan  Not the appropriate place for arguments but you are splitting hairs.  What I'm saying is that rotation is NOT the only thing that can cause your activity to restart and writing code as if it were, which the poorly judged use of configChanges supports, is a source of many bugs.  There are many good reasons why by default a rotation kills the activity and at least as many good discussions on the web about why it is so.  It most certainly is not brain dead.

Comment: @Simon I think you're conflating arguments, this question isn't about lifecycles but about rotation.  And sorry, I've never seen it not create more problems than it caused.  It is brain dead, as are a large number of decisions that Android devs made.  But I think we'll just have to agree to disagree here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a catastrophic UX if an application loses its state just because I went to the settings to change the screen brightness. This happens frequently on 512MB RAM devices - which are still sold in large quantities. There are even devices with 256MB produced right now.

Yes, it happens a lot. It will happen to certain users much more frequent than to others. Those users will have no pardon with your app.

Comment: I have a 192 MB device! The answer is yes as there are many reasons your app may have its Activities killes - memory issues - many config changes etc

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on the type of screens you are developing. When the activity contains a lot of data for example, it should be convenient to save the state of your activity (not all activities).

If you have several fields that the user must refill, it can be a bad experience especially if the virtual keyboard of device is not that easy (assume you are using a Galaxy mini for example)

In other words, it is a good practice but its up to you to decide if the user experience will be degraded or not

Serge

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I have written several single orientation apps for our current product and I feel that it's still important to save state.  It just makes for a more usable application when everything is how you left it when you return.

In general, it's not that much work either.  First, keep in mind that if you assign an ID to views in your layout's, the default Activity.onSaveInstanceState() will do most of the work.  It will remember Checkbox states, EditText contents, etc.  There are relatively few things you need to save.  Here are some of the things I've saved with the state:

- Relevant Activity parameters
- ListView position information
- Current Tab in TabView

Activity parameters are by far the most common.